# Stop all current exchanges on all routes and clear aggregator

Tags: java, apache-camel

I throw an exception and I catch the exception with `onException()`.

Is it possible to stop all current exchanges on all routes? When I' using `.stop()` only the actual exchange routing will stop. But exchanges in aggregator will still be routed. How can I clear (remove all exchanges from) the aggregator?

Comment: It has Java and JMX API you can use to obtain information about the state of the aggregator, and as well there is API on the AggregationRepository. Also it depends what you mean with remove a group, eg what should happen to that group that is being removed. Do you mean it should complete and its output be routed?

Comment: @ClausIbsen It should be marked as completed and then thrown away. Because I know there won't be an regular completion and I don't want to get a timeout.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I edited the question a little.